# For disjoint compacts sets, is $d(E_1, E_2,...,E_m)>0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have sets $E_1, E_2,...,E_m$ be subsets in $R^n$. If $$d(E_1, E_2,...,E_m)=\inf\{d(x_i,x_j); x_i\in E_i,x_j\in E_j, 1\le i<j\le m\}$$ My question is: Suppose $E_1, E_2,...,E_m$ are nonempty, disjoint, compact sets, is  $d(E_1, E_2,...,E_m)>0$?

I know this doesn't hold for infinite many $E_k$. However, I am not sure if this is true if we have only finite many $E_K$.

Intuitively, I believe this is true for the finite case.

Could anyone tell if this is right? Thanks！

Comment: Why do you state the question for $m$ sets instead of just two sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x_i,y_i$, each of which is in one of the $E_1,\ldots,E_m$ for which $d(x_i,y_i)$ converges to the infimum. Then there is some $E_k$ that $x_i$ is in $E_k$ infinitely many times, take a subsequence along which all the $x_i$ are in $E_k$. From that subsequence, the $y_i$ must be in some $E_l \neq E_k$ infinitely many times, so take a further subsequence for which $y_i$ is in $E_k$. Take a further subsequence on which the $x_i$ converge, and then an even further subsequence on which the $y_i$ converge. You will find that you have $x \in E_k, y \in E_l$ such that $d(x,y)$ achieves the infimum distance. Since $E_k, E_l$ are disjoint, $d(x,y) > 0$, and hence the inf is $>0$.